# Fastcgi crash "asked to stop immediately"

Tags: fastcgi, ruby-on-rails, shared-hosting

I'm trying to upload files in a rails app with the paperclip gem on shared hosting with bluehost.  It works fine locally, but on bluehost whenever I try to upload the file I just get redirected to the index, and a new log file pops up called `fastcgi.crash.log` in my `log` directory.  It says:

```
[18/Nov/2009:09:12:19 :: 23593] asked to stop immediately
[18/Nov/2009:09:12:19 :: 23593] stopping after explicit exit
[18/Nov/2009:09:12:23 :: 3679] starting
```

My raw access file looks like:

```
67.182.234.77 - - [18/Nov/2009:09:12:32 -0700] "POST /images HTTP/1.1" 301 421 "http://paperclip.ryanflorence.com/images/new" "user agent stuff"
```

Why it's giving a 301 permanently moved redirect is strange ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I just had this same problem on Hostmonster... I did two things that fixed it.

1. I was using the same route that you are above, a POST request to /images ... I think fcgi gets this confused somehow with the route for /public/images ... Adding a route for /image_uploads changed my error to a 422.
2. To fix the 422, I realized that I had removed the line from my /config/initializers/session_store.rb to use Active Record sessions. After re-adding

ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store

to sessions_store.rb my uploads were working :-) hope this helps.